# SQL database login for 'Sharepoint_Config' on instance '' failed. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

in an application server where performancepoint service and secure store service running i saw below error many times, how to solve this errors

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Foundation
Date:          4/14/2016 4:41:01 PM
Event ID:      3351
Task Category: Database
Level:         Critical
Keywords:      
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      BI.Domain.com
Description:
SQL database login for ‘ Sharepoint_Config' on instance 'XXXXXX_SQL' failed. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\BI$'.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <EventID>3351</EventID>
    <Version>15</Version>
    <Level>1</Level>
    <Task>3</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-04-14T13:41:01.657524100Z" />
    <EventRecordID>164104</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{2F69DF1A-4421-0006-A869-772F2144D101}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="26264" ThreadID="20128" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>BI.xxxxxx.com</Computer>
```

Comment: do you know about this id DOMAIN\BI$? what is this use?

Comment: Domain is the name of our domain and in BI$ BI is application server name its not user name

Comment: and this error is only bi server or all server?

Comment: do you have monitoring or 3rd part tool install on the server?

Comment: no i have no 3rd party tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change permission for SharePoint_Config database, you can do as follows:

Login to SQL Server Management Studio under Database Engine using authorized login account.
Expand Security tree and then r-click on Logins > New Login
Click Search and then type your new login account (remember that you must use fully structure domain_name\user_name)
After creating new login account, expand Databases tree, r-click on SharePoint_Config database and then select Properties.
Click Permission setting, select account and then select permission you want to assign for account.
Another Resolution

This error occurs because the SharePoint Timer service cannot log on to the SharePoint_Config database on the instance of Microsoft SQL Server that is used by SharePoint. To deploy Microsoft Dynamics NAV Portal Framework, Microsoft Dynamics NAV Setup creates a SharePoint Timer job through the SharePoint application programming interface (API). The SharePoint Timer must have access to the SharePoint_Config database.

To resolve this issue, add the logon account of the SharePoint Timer service as a user of the SharePoint_Config database. Give role membership to the account db_owner.